# automatically save the current buffer when is going to edit a new file

Tags: vim

I've made some changes in the current buffer, and I want vim to automatically save the current buffer when I'm going to edit a new file with the following command:

```
:e another_file_which_is_not_a_buffer_in_vim_yet
```

I added the following line in my `.vimrc` file, but it didn't work.

```
autocmd BufLeave * update
```

Vim still prompted me `No write since last change`, why? How can I make it work? By the way, I only want to save the current buffer instead of all buffers, because saving all buffers seems to mess up the order of the buffers, which would bring trouble when I run `:bp` or `:bn`.

Comment: It isn't precisely your proposed solution, but do you know about `:set hidden`? See `:help hidden` which will allow you switch buffers while leaving one unsaved. You may then edit new ones and cycle among the existing ones freely, but Vim will complain if you attempt to quit while any are unsaved.

Comment: I found a way to make it work. Just add `au TextChanged * update` and `au InsertLeave * update` in `.vimrc`. It will automatically save the current buffer when the text is changed. So vim won't complain when leaving a buffer. Working in vim(7.4). Not exactly the right answer technically, so I put it here as a comment in hopes that it might be helpful to somebody.

Answer (score 13):

Vim has an option to save also for, among others, `:edit` in addition to what triggers `autowrite`:

```
set autowriteall
```

Relevant manual excerpts:

[`autowrite`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#'autowrite'):

> ```
> 'autowrite' 'aw'  boolean (default off)
>                   global
>   Write the contents of the file, if it has been modified, on each
>   :next, :rewind, :last, :first, :previous, :stop, :suspend, :tag, :!,
>   :make, CTRL-] and CTRL-^ command; and when a :buffer, CTRL-O, CTRL-I,
>   '{A-Z0-9}, or `{A-Z0-9} command takes one to another file.
>   Note that for some commands the 'autowrite' option is not used, see
>   'autowriteall' for that.
> ```

and [`autowriteall`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#'autowriteall'):

> ```
> 'autowriteall' 'awa'  boolean (default off)
>                       global
>                       {not in Vi}
>   Like 'autowrite', but also used for commands ":edit", ":enew", ":quit",
>   ":qall", ":exit", ":xit", ":recover" and closing the Vim window.
>   Setting this option also implies that Vim behaves like 'autowrite' has
>   been set.
> ```

Answer (score 3):

This line of code shold do the trick. Place it inside `.vimrc` file. Location of this `.vimrc` file can be found if you type `:version` inside of vim.

```
set autowrite
```

More about this topic can be found on this [link](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Auto_save_files_when_focus_is_lost)

Comment: It works most of the time, but if you do this, it doesn't work: delete a line in the current buffer using `dd`, then edit a new file with `:e /tmp/new_file`, vim will prompt you `No write since last change` after that. You have to `write` the current buffer manually in this case.

Comment: Yes, it's little buggy, but this may help `:au FocusLost * :wa` This will save all changes for all named buffers. There are no solutions for unnamed buffers yet.